# Spring Data Jpa: OneToOne mappedBy property always returning null

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have several `@OneToOne` Relations in my application and all of them have the same issue. 
One Example:

Entity 1:

```
@Entity
class OfferPagePanel(
        @OneToOne
     var offerPage: OfferPage,
)
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
abstract class OfferPage(
        var title: String
){

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="page")
    var ogTag: OgTag? = null

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="offerPage")
    var panel: OfferPagePanel? = null
}
```

Problem:

```
    fun someServiceFunction(){
        offerPage.panel //This is always null, even though a matching panel is in the database
         offerPagePanelRepository.findByPage(offerPage) //this returns the correct panel
    }
```

(Syntax in KT in case you wonder)

Comment: `@OneToOne` is usually used in conjunction with `@JoinColumn` to tell hibernate which column to map, especially when other side has `mappedBy`.

Please see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: `mappedBy="page"` -> `mappedBy="offerPage"`?

Comment: @KedarJoshi `@JoinColumn` defines schema info and nothing else in this context, so is of no value here

Comment: @pirho No, you are looking @ wrong property

Comment: @BillyFrost yes you are right, this will change nothing

Comment: Yes I do not know what I was looking but my comment was wrong as I now look at the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. i did

```
val offerPage = repository.getOne(id)
```

But that basically returns an empty shell.
once loaded via `findOne(id)` it works and Hibernate can use a proxy to load the Entity once the property gets called...